# How to call microservice-2 from microservice-1 using python?

Tags: python, flask, microservices

How to call my microservice-2 from microservice-1. So our result looks like this:-

> Result :- {“message”: “vivek”} --> {“message”: “keviv”, “random”: 3.89}

command to access microservice-1:-

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/reverse_random/vivek
```

microservice-1

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/reverse_reandom/<string:string>', methods=['GET'])
def reverse(string):
    string = string[::-1]
    return jsonify({'message': string })


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

microservice-2

```
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def myRandom():
    r1 = random.uniform(0, 10)
    return jsonify({'message': r1 })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you syntax error in microservice-2. 3rd line should be  `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: moreover, you should run the second micro service on a different port if you use the same machine for running both servers

Comment: In my case, I need to create two different containers for these two microservices.Example:-  container-1 with microservice-1, container-2 with microservice-2.

Comment: ok. in docker containers? did you try to wrap the code provided in answers? it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it works, need to make a docker image container now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run microservice-2 on a different port. Send request using Python standard or 3rd party library from microservice-1
to microservice-2 upon request to microservice-1.

Below is the example of using Python3 standard library only:

**m1.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import urllib
import json 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/reverse_random/<string:string>', methods=['GET'])
def reverse(string):
    content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:5001').read().decode('utf-8')
    print('response from m2: ', content)
    string = string[::-1]
    return jsonify({'message': string, 'random' : json.loads(content)['message']})


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

**m2.py**:

```
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def myRandom():
    r1 = random.uniform(0, 10)

    return jsonify({'message': r1 })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001) # running m2 on a different port than default 5000
```

Run the m1: `python3 m1.py`

Run the m2 in a different shell: `python3 m2.py`

Send request to m1: `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/reverse_random/vivek`

The result is:

```
{ 
  "message": "keviv",  
  "random": 4.138115905045612 
}
```

Observe the log of m1 and of m2 to make sure m2 was invoked.

Comment: what if i have parameters in microservice1 that i need to pass to microservice 2?

Answer (score 4):

you'll need to issue a `GET` request to `service 2` in order to get the random number, I suggest to use [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) for this, like

```
r = requests.get('url-for-service-2:port/')
data = r.json()
random_num = data['message']
```

*keep in mind to check the `data` object for `message` key, or using `.get()` or equivalent*

Answer (score 0):

To connect between services you can use background tasks such as `celery` and `ramq` or use `nsq` and `nats`